# Prevent firing HTML button serverclick event if form validation fails?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I am trying validate form before HTML button serverclick event fires. But client and server events are happening at same time.

### HTML

```
<button runat="server" id="imgLogin" type="submit" class="btn" style="width:6em">
        <img src="Images/arrow_plain_green_E.png" alt="" />
               Login
 </button>
```

### Javascript

```
 var form = $("#form1");
        $('#<%=imgLogin.ClientID%>').click(function (e) {
            if (!form.valid()) {
                e.preventDefault(); // Stop form submit here only 
                                    //   if form validate false
            } 
        });
```

### server code

```
Protected Sub imgLogin_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles imgLogin.ServerClick
    'logic here
End Sub
```

I am unable to form submit if form validate fails. ServerClick is firing automatically.

How to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you not using an ASP.NET button control and [ASP.NET validator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debza5t0%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)s to achieve this?

Most of what you want to do can be achieved without writing any javascript in this way.o